# How to open aptitude downloaded packages?

Tags: aptitude

I just downloaded VirtualBox 5.2 from the terminal using aptitude. This was my command:

```
sudo aptitude install virtualbox-5.2
```

Now I want to open the package but, there are no know commands(to my knowledge). Can anybody help me?

Comment: I don't know your release of Ubuntu, nor your source for the package, but I have installed `virtualbox` (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=virtualbox&searchon=names) for my release, and it appears in the menus (under "system tools" as I'm using Lubuntu 19.10).  Using the search function of menu system it'll locate it with just "vir" if I don't want to navigate and find it in submenus.

Comment: Do you wish to *run (use)* virtualbox, or *open the downloaded package to inspect its contents*?  Your question can be interpreted either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to know what files are the package contains you can use

```
dpkg-deb --contents /path/to/your.deb
```

if you want to extract the files use

```
dpkg-deb --extract /path/to/your.deb /path/to/folder/you want them.
```